# OpenFire/Redmine service autostart

Tags: autostart, init

We are using OpenFire chat service in the office on a Ubuntu server. Everyday I have to enter a command to start it. The command line is `sudo su - service openfire start`. I also start the Redmine service using this command `./ctlscript.sh start` in the Redmine directory. Can we make these services autostart during boot?

Answer (score 2):

For openfire, you can try:

```
update-rc.d openfire defaults
```

For redmine, please read http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/9334